# Yii 2 advanced. Не работает консоль из-за отсутствия файла yii

Tags: yii2, консоль

Мне, в качестве, задания поступил проект, который надо доработать. Но консольные команды в нем не работают: ошибка - Could not file: yii. Не могу из-за этого сгенирировать конфиги для интернационализации. Как быть? Костыли делать вручную или можно как то восстановить функционал консоли?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Файла init также нет

Comment: зайдите в репозиторий yii и скачайте от туда недостающие фалы

Comment: Увы, не помогает, данный способ

Comment: дайте более детальную информацию, полный текст ошибок

Comment: При добавлении файлов с гита и попытки инициализации или выполнения других консольных команд появляется такая ошибка:

**Warning: require(D:/OSPanel/domains/lk.ru/environments/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\OSPanel\domains\lk.ru\init on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'D:/OSPanel/domains/lk.ru/environments/index.php' (include_path='.;D:/laragon/etc/php/pear') in D:\OSPanel\domains\lk.ru\init on line 17**

Comment: Использую OpenServer

Comment: Ну так скачайте еще и папку environments :)